# How would I initialize Data = new double[rowCount][columnCount] in C#

Tags: c#

In Java, I can say:

```
private double[][] data;
```

and initialize it:

```
Data = new double[rowCount][columnCount]
```

However, in C#, I would say

```
private double[][] Data { get; set; }
```

How would I initialize it in the same way in C#?

*EDIT*

Here's the class so far in C#:

```
namespace Carnotaurus.UtilityPack.Models.StatModels.Matrices
{
    public class Matrix
    {

        public int RowCount { get; }

        public int ColumnCount { get; }

        public double[][] Data { get; set; }

        public Matrix(double[][] dat)
        {
            Data = dat;
            RowCount = dat.Length;
            ColumnCount = dat[0].Length;
        }

        public Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount)
        {
            RowCount = rowCount;
            ColumnCount = columnCount;
            //Data = new double[rowCount][columnCount];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disregard my previous answer, I had a brain fart.)*

In C#, we have two different kinds of multidimensional arrays. There are square arrays (`double[,]`) and jagged arrays (`double[][]`).

Square arrays are true multidimensional arrays. The first dimension has a set length of sub-arrays, and each array in the second dimension has a set length as well, and so on. They are commonly used to define things like grids or cartesian graphs. You define and initialize them like so:

```
public double[,] Data { get; set; }

public Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount)
{
    Data = new double[rowCount, columnCount];
}
```

Jagged arrays are treated as "arrays of arrays". Each sub-array is basically a distinct array, and may or may not have the same length as all of its sibling arrays. As such, each child array must be initialized separately. They are declared and initialized like so:

```
public double[][] Data { get; set; }

public Matrix(int rowCount, int columnCount)
{
    Data = new double[rowCount][];

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++)
    {
        Data[i] = new double[columnCount];
    }
}
```

There isn't really any fixed limit to how many dimensions you can go to with either array type. For example, you can have a 10th dimensional square array:

```
double[,,,,,,,,,] Data;
```

... or jagged array:

```
double[][][][][][][][][][] Data;
```

... though I'd recommend that you have a darn good reason for making arrays with that many dimensions. :P